How do we get TS to see correlation between arguments, in the function body?
How can we get TS to understand that two properties of a destructured object argument are related, from within the function body?
Here are my two attempts:
type Type<T extends string | number> = {
  one: T;
  two: T extends string ? number : string;
};
function foo<T extends string | number>({ one, two }: Type<T>) {
  if (typeof one === "string") {
    two;
  } else {
    two;
  }
}

foo({one: 'one', two: 'two'})
foo({one: 'one', two: 2})

function bar({ one, two }: { one: string; two: number }): void;
function bar({ one, two }: { one: number; two: string }): void;
function bar<T extends string | number>({
  one,
  two,
}: {
  one: string | number;
  two: string | number;
}): void {
  if (typeof one === "string") {
    two;
  } else {
    two;
  }
}


bar({one: 'one', two: 'two'})
bar({one: 'one', two: 2})

As seen, both examples narrow down the ways the function can be called, but neither of them have an effect inside the function body.
Playground.

This is effectively two questions. One is: why don't generics narrow inside the function? The answer there is: "because it's not type safe, your generics don't behave the way you think they do in the face of unions, see this playground link." The second is: why don't overloads narrow function bodies? and the answer is "it's too complex, see ms/TS#52478 for example". Which of those would you like to explore in depth here? Please [edit] to pick one, if possible.

Ugh, Typescript has so many edge cases where the compiler just does not do what intuition would expect. It feels like it is harder to become proficient in the type system than the underlying language. When the TS compiler is unable to infer / narrow a type we can clearly see as humans, we will have to continuously work to re-write even the most basic code, just to make the compiler happy. Oh well, enough complaining. Thank you for the clarifying questions, @jcalz, perhaps it is best to focus on generics. It seems like using a type parameter is the best approach to correlating two parameters.

@jcalz I looked at your playground and found it surprising you were allowed to do that call with the random values, as it does not guarantee that the two arguments are the inverse of each other. The object type I have written (Type), specifically asks for the two properties to be inversed, via a conditional type. I do not understand why there is any ambiguity there. When that call is allowed, I understand that the function body is not narrowed, but the way I see it, that call does not respect Type and should not have been allowed in the first place.

If you decide to write an answer, @jcalz, could you please also address how correlating two object properties in a function argument is most commonly done in Typescript? The destructuring pattern for arguments, i.e. named parameters, is common in React code, for instance. I encounter the need to do this on a daily basis, so I can only assume that this is something that others also frequently encounter. As such, there is probably a common way to enforce the correlation of the properties in the object argument, both in the function call and in the function body.

One more point @jcalz, please see the bottom example in this playground: https://tsplay.dev/NlZPrW. Meaning, when using the generic approach above, it is suddenly impossible to use default values. Does that mean we are forced to go the overload route?

PS: In my actual code I have had to do something as ridiculous and bloated as this, to make it work (I have removed some parts for simplicity): https://tsplay.dev/NV8PvW

A lot of comments here, but placing something like this in the body also does not make TS understand that two should be defined whenever one is passed in: if (one && !two) { throw new Error('One should be passed in whenever two is given.') }. I am using the real code example, and not the string | number example, but the same issue applies.

Hmm, could you please [edit] the post to ask a single clear question? Right now the combination of the comments and the addendum to the original question still makes me think you're asking multiple things here. For my sanity I can only really focus on one, and then if there are followups they can go in their own question posts. In general, TS only does narrowing in specific supported/idiomatic situations; it's not a proof/constraint solver, so just because something might be logically true doesn't mean TS can deduce it. But for specifics, I need to see a concise and focused single question.

@jcalz I have now done my best to clarify and state one single question. The code snippets are just my own attempts. Not sure if I can make it any clearer.

The answer to this question is now: TS does not support this, you'll need to use assertions or the like. TS only supports narrowing destructured discriminated unions, and {one: string, two: number} | {one: number, two: string} is not a discriminated union. If you change to a discriminated union like this playground link then it works. Otherwise you need to use some other narrowing technique (like type guard functions) and give up on destructuring. Does that now fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate. If not what's missing?

@jcalz thank you, that does address the question.

TypeScript doesn't in general track correlations between multiple variables. Its control flow analysis only pays attention to how a check on a particular variable affects that variable.  Even if it is logically provable that exactly one of a pair of variables one and two is of type string and the other is of type number, TypeScript's control flow analysis is not a proof solver. If you check one, then it can narrow one, but two is unaffected.  See microsoft/TypeScript#54252 and issues linked within for this general limitation of TypeScript.
There is some support, though, in the specific case where your multiple variables are destructured from a discriminated union. Then if you check the variable corresponding to the discriminant property, the other variables will be narrowed. In some sense it's just re-using the support for discriminated union narrowing.
But your example doesn't satisfy this condition. You can say that the destructured object {one, two} is of a union type {one: string, two: number} | {one: number, two: string}. But it's not a discriminated union. Neither string nor number are literal types, so checking one still has no effect on two.
If you could change your code so that it's a discriminated union, then sure, it will work:
function foo({ one, two, type }:
  { type: "oneStr", one: string, two: number } |
  { type: "twoStr", one: number, two: string }
) {
  if (type === "oneStr") {
    one;
    //^? (parameter) one: string
    two;
    //^? (parameter) two: number
  } else {
    one;
    //^? (parameter) one: number
    two;
    //^? (parameter) two: string
  }
}

foo({ type: 'oneStr', one: 'one', two: 2 }); // okay
foo({ type: 'oneStr', one: 'one', two: 'two' }) // error
foo({
  type: Math.random() < 0.999 ? 'oneStr' : 'twoStr',
  one: 'one', two: 2
}) // error

I've added the type property to the input, and if you check type inside the function body, it narrows both one and two.
If that doesn't work for you then you need to give up on automatic narrowing in the function body. You could use type assertions. Or you could not destructure and use a custom type guard function on the input object. But none of these are what you're asking for specifically, so ‍♂️.
Playground link to code

Awesome, thank you for the explaining context. Quick question: You say that TS has limited support for correlating variables, but is that not exactly what type parameters are for? At least when used with conditional types. To correlate an input parameter with the return value of a function: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html

...(continuing from previous) What originally confused me is that TS seems to be perfectly capable of correlating input and output (i.e. parameters and return values, ref. conditional types with type parameters), but correlating two parameters is suddenly not supported.

If you call a generic function with a type argument then the return type will be evaluated from that. This isn't the same as correlating multiple variable types via control flow analysis. Type info flows forward with control flow, mostly. If I have const x: X and const f: <T>(t: T)=>F<T> and const z = f(x) then of course z is of type F<X>. But if later we learn that z is actually of type F<Y> for Y extends X, this doesn't retroactively narrow x to Y. TS isn't a proof solver. Comments aren't good for followup qs; if there's more you might want to open a new post.

You have several complications here like destructuring (which destroys any correlation between one and two  variables (not props) - they become totally independent variables. Plus generic conditional type isn't narrowed.
You could refactor to something like that if suitable:
Playground
type Type1 = {
  one: string;
  two: number;
}

type Type2 = {
  one: number;
  two: string;
};

const isType1 = (arg: Type1 | Type2): arg is Type1 => typeof arg.one === 'string';

function foo(type: Type1 | Type2) {
  if (isType1(type)) {
    type.two // number
  } else {
    type.two // string
  }
}

foo({one: 'one', two: 'two'})
foo({one: 'one', two: 2})


The destructuring only destroys the correlation because the union is not a discriminated union.  Destructuring disciminated unions is supported (so if it were like this it would just work). But yes, there are multiple complications in the question.

Thank you, Alexander. Does this mean that the common argument destructuring pattern (aka. named parameters), often used in React among others, does not really work in TS, if we want to correlate input variables?

It surprises me that destructuring brakes the correlation between the argument's properties. In the type I assigned to the object argument, the type parameter clearly states the correlation between the two properties. How come that is not respected by the compiler?

Additional clarifying question: How come a type predicate is needed? It seems obvious, at least to the human eye, that the two are inversely correlated, just by looking at their types directly (i.e. a normal typeof type guard, instead of a predicate).

@Magnus destructuring doesn't break this correlation, it just doesn't keep it for the variables that an object was destructured to

@Magnus yes, it's silly (as many other things in TS) that typeof doesn't work, if one would be specific values it would be a tagged union and TS would work with like if(type.one ==='type1')

Ugh, frustrating. One of the reasons destructuring is popular is that it makes it easy to set default values within the argument. That is not possible with the generic approach, right? Would you use overload functions instead, for the goal of correlating two properties in a named property, i.e. an object argument? Bottom example here illustrates the problem: https://tsplay.dev/NlZPrW

@Magnus remember that TS is a subset of JS (though superset is claimed everywhere), so it supports limited features of JS, for the default value try: export interface Type2<T extends boolean = false> {   one?: T | false;   two?: T extends true ? string : never; } 

Thank you, that does work. How did you go about learning TS to this extent? I have read everything in the official handbook, and countless articles and SO posts, yet still cannot achieve something basic like this without help. Thanks again for sharing.

I spotted one more issue in the playground I sent two comments back. It allows passing true for one, then no two argument. It should be "if one is passed in and is true, then two must be string. Otherwise, two must not be permitted to be passed in. It should also be OK to pass neither." Is that possible?

@Magnus can you make it as a new question and i would answer? for this particular case: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=5.8.0-dev.20241202#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgJYDs4hgMwIYGMQIAqAnhCAEwA8hC46KAJgM4IBGUUANiNiggLwIcnJiAB8CAN7AECKChAB+AFxEEAHyHYRIANwyEcAO5QVauiEYs4MAK4FFCJjdQBzBKoUA3DPoC+wKCQsIiYtii4cEjybNgAXtS0YPTMbBzcvAJaOmIAFNKy8gSCwqIANAbGUBV+qiRkVIRiAJSqXlBIDFIGRZUmwAHArPH5fs1DI5JFqjb2YxNx+dOGdiBlhiaqAOSYHFvzw4tTCqqlaxtQ27tQ+81AA

For future visitors, the other question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79247972/how-to-correlate-two-properties-in-a-destructured-object-argument
