How to correlate two properties in a destructured object argument?
I am trying to correlate the externalFlag and domain properties of the below function, with the following requirements:

It should be permitted to omit both externalFlag and domain, but if externalFlag is passed in as true then domain must be string.
Object destructuring must be possible for the argument.
If externalFlag is not passed in, it should default to false (set in the destructuring).
TS inside the function body must understand that if externalFlag is true, then domain is string.

The code, i.e. my own attempt, where the function body requirement above is not upheld (playground):
interface BaseProps {
  someProp?: boolean;
}

type ExternalProps = {
  externalFlag: true;
  domain: string;
} & BaseProps

type InternalProps = {
  externalFlag: false;
} & BaseProps;

type CombinedProps = {
  externalFlag?: boolean;
  domain?: string;
} & BaseProps;

function fun({
  someProp,
}: InternalProps | ExternalProps | BaseProps): void;
function fun({
  externalFlag = false,
  someProp = false,
  domain,
}: CombinedProps) {
  if(externalFlag) {
    domain
  } else {
    domain
  }
}

fun({})
fun({ externalFlag: true})
fun({ externalFlag: true, domain: ''})
fun({ externalFlag: false})

I am OK with any solution, i.e. generics or overloads, but it would be great with an explanation of why it works as it does, and which approach is more "common".

There's no solution with defaults, it's a bug (or a design limitation) as described in ms/TS#50139. You'll have to wait for this to be fixed, or you can fix it yourself since the bug is listed as "help wanted". Otherwise you need to work around it by using type assertions or the like. There might be a clunky crazy workaround that's closer to safe but it's not "common". The common thing is to give up on the function body requirement and be careful implementing it. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write up an a; if not, what's missing?

Thanks @jcalz. I could give up on the default value, and just assign that in the body somehow (instead of in the destrcuturing), but I need the narrowing in the function body. If TS does not understand that the two arguments are correlated from within the function body, only from the outside (when called), then half the purpose is lost. I would have to double up all my type guards inside the function body, to include both properties, and cover a ton of additional scenarios. Is what I am asking possible if we drop the "default in destrcuturing" requirement?

Yes, you can do it like this (note that undefined is falsy so you don't need false there as default with your check). Does that fully address the question now?

@jcalz Ah, that works, without any type parameter or overloads. Hmmm, there is some fundamental knowledge I have missed here. If you have time to write an answer with an explanation of why that solution works, that would be deeply appreciated. Thank you.

TypeScript supports control flow analysis for destructured discriminated unions. If we slightly modify your types to be
type ExternalProps = {
  externalFlag: true;
  domain: string;
} & BaseProps

type InternalProps = {
  externalFlag?: false;
  domain?: never;
} & BaseProps;

type CombinedProps =
  InternalProps | ExternalProps;

then CombinedProps is a discriminated union where the externalFlag property is a discriminant. Note that discriminant properties need to contain literal types. The boolean literals true and false and the unit/literal type undefined are valid discriminant types, so checking for externalFlag being either true or false | undefined suffices to narrow the union.
Now your function can be written as
function fun({
  externalFlag, domain, someProp }: CombinedProps): void {
  if (externalFlag) {
    domain
    //^? (parameter) domain: string
  } else {
    domain
    //^? (parameter) domain: undefined
  }
}

and you can see it works as intended.

Note that I've used the fact that undefined is falsy, instead of using a destructuring assignment default of false.
TypeScript currently doesn't support control flow analysis for destructured discriminated unions if it uses defaults. This is considered a bug, as described in microsoft/TypeScript#50139, although the implementer of the original feature said it's a limitation. Anyway, until and unless this gets fixed (and you can do this yourself if you want because it's marked as "Help Wanted"), you have to give up on defaults if you want the narrowing to happen.
Playground link to code
